# MS Outlook email alert

Tags: microsoft-outlook, notifications, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have all MS Outlook notifications disabled (see screenshot below) in order to not get distracted at work.

However I would like to receive a notification if an email meets certain criteria (based on title).

Is it possible to achieve this in MS Outlook 2016?

[image]

Comment: How did you have all MS Outlook notifications disabled? Set mailbox rules to test it.

Comment: Hi Sue, thanks for asking. I've edited the original question and added a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with message rules. You can setup a rule to match certain types of incoming mail and then have Outlook do something - like play a sound, or display a notification.

https://www.howtogeek.com/239131/how-to-get-outlook-notifications-for-important-emails-only/

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. Appleoddity's post shared more samples.

You can also just check the ***Subject contains*** box and type the (key) words in the title as conditions, like below:

[image]